# How to customize Table of contents in thesis

Tags: thesis

I need help in formatting thesis. I m using isuthesis class. My university guidelines doesnt match with isuthesis TABLE OF CONTENTS STYLE

ACCORDING TO UNIVERSITY, The format for typing TABLE OF CONTENTS,LIST OF TABLES LIST OF FIGURES,ABBREVATION and NOTATION etc.  are explained through the following illustrative examples.

[image]

LIST OF TABLES shown below

[image]

LIST OF TABLES shown below

[image]

ABBREVATION and NOTATION are shown below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some general remarks:

- Check once again, e.g. by looking at old theses in the library, how the specification is really meant. Some notes on the pages that you show us look to me rather as *meta-comments*. E.g., the subtitle *(List in the alphabetical order)* (apart from not sounding like proper English) doesn't make sense if included literally (an alphabetically sorted list is easily recognized as being sorted) but makes sense if interpreted as an instruction to the author of the thesis. Likewise, a label *Page No.* above the list of page numbers (in a table of contents) is stating the obvious and is redundant; my guess is that it is rather a comment addressing the prospective author of the thesis.
- Ask your fellow-students, the officers in the dean's office or in the administration for a ready-made LaTeX-template for theses. It doesn't make much sense if each student starts anew to compose such a template, which is non-trivial for a novice.
- Finally, it is not a good idea to pick a rather arbitrary class from another university and then to try to tweak it to the requirements of your university. Such thesis classes are often quite messy or just special (`ucithesis.cls` is no exception); adapting them to your requirements is more cumbersome than to start from a standard class. Below I chose `book.cls` as a starting point, because it offers some features useful for larger documents.

Here is the table of contents produced by the code below it. I'm sure you will have some more requirements; my hope is that the code below is a suitable starting point. Ask on this site if you need further help.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\renewcommand\contentsname{CONTENTS}
\renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES}
\addtocontents{toc}{{\bfseries Contents\hfill Page No.\bigskip\par}}
\addtocontents{lot}{{\bfseries No.\hfill Title\hfill\hfill Page No.\bigskip\par}}
\addtocontents{lof}{{\bfseries No.\hfill Title\hfill\hfill Page No.\bigskip\par}}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor,xpatch}
\renewcommand\cftbeforechapskip{0ex}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter~}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{. }
\newlength\tocindent
\settowidth\tocindent{\cftchapfont\cftchappresnum9\cftchapaftersnum}
\edef\cftchapnumwidth{\the\tocindent}
\edef\cftsecindent{\the\tocindent}
\advance\tocindent2.3em
\edef\cftsubsecindent{\the\tocindent}
\advance\tocindent3.2em
\edef\cftsubsubsecindent{\the\tocindent}
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecdotsep{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecdotsep{\cftnodots}
\newcommand\tocmainmatter
  {\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\color{white}}%
  }
\xapptocmd\mainmatter{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\tocmainmatter}}{}{}


\newif\ifschaptertoc
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makeschapterhead[1]%
 {{\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
  }%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
  \ifschaptertoc
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
  \fi
 }
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\schaptertoctrue

\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}
\blindtext

\chapter*{ABSTRACT}
\blindtext

\listoftables

\listoffigures

\chapter*{ABBREVIATIONS}
\Blindtext

\chapter*{NOTATIONS}
\Blindtext

\mainmatter

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\blindtext

\section{General Background}
\blindtext

\section{Objective}
\blindtext
\subsection{Objective 1}
\blindtext
\subsection{Objective 2}
\blindtext
\subsection{Objective 3}
\blindtext

\section{Scheme}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: I hope this is a mixup. I cannot believe that there are universities out there that publish guidelines like that. Without making clear what is actual sample document and what are formatting annotations. If this is the real deal, may some deity have mercy on us.